# Getting (Long, String) from (String) => Try[(Long, String)]

Tags: scala

I have a method that return `(String) => Try[(Long, String)]` type and I want to get `(Long, String)`. Any suggestion?

I thought map/flatMap will help but looks like they doesn't.

**Update**

```
def someMethod():(Long, String) = {
  val result: (String) => Try[(Long, String)] = someOperation()
  //Need to get (Long, String) from result
}
```

Comment: `.toOption.getOrElse( default )` ?

Comment: @All just updated with sample code to explain my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several options

```
val exceptional: Try[(Long, String)] = ???
val default: (Long, String) = (0, "")
```

Providing fallback value

```
exceptional.getOrElse(default)
```

handling exception and then safely `get`

```
exceptional.recover { case exception => default }.get
```

or using pattern matching

```
exceptional match {
  case Success(v) => v
  case Failure(exception) => default
}
```